# Aggregate every 3 days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table

| datetime | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-21 11:23:00 | 1 |
| 2022-10-22 12:12:00 | 2 |
| 2022-10-23 13:43:00 | 0 |
| 2022-10-24 14:01:00 | 5 |
| 2022-10-25 10:23:00 | 2 |

and I would like to get a result like this (aggregate each 3 days), gaps are possible

| datetime | value |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-21 - 2022-10-23 | 3 |
| 2022-10-24 - 2022-10-25 | 7 |

How can I do that?

Comment: Does it matter which three days? What if it did 19-21, 22-24, 25-27? Should gaps change which dates aggregate? If a day is missing, shoukdnuttb search forward for the next date, so the each group always has three rows contributing to it?

Comment: *"gaps are possible"* does not inform us how to treat gaps exactly. Also: your version of Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select row number for each row, then apply aggregate SUM function on group of each 3 rows.

```
SELECT 
  MIN(date_time) AS start_date, 
  MAX(date_time) AS end_date, 
  SUM(value) AS value 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      *, 
      ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY date_time) AS row_index 
    FROM 
      your_table
  ) AS data 
GROUP BY 
  (row_index - 1)/ 3;
```

You could try it here: https://onecompiler.com/postgresql/3yv74qc4p

Comment: Notice that this solution only works when there is only one row per date and no gaps. Also, the output is different from the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

`lag` can be used to find all `datetime`s that constitute the start of a day range and then in a recursive `cte`, the subsquent `datetime`s in its range can be joined onto it. Additionally, the `cte` tracks the count of the day interval, producing an `id` which can be used to separate day ranges into groups of three:

```sql
with recursive cte(id, dt, val, cnt, r_num) as (
   select t1.datetime, t1.datetime, t1.value, 0, 0 from (
       select t.*, date(lag(t.datetime, 1) over (order by t.datetime)) != date(t.datetime) - interval '1 day' s 
       from tbl t) t1 
   where t1.s is null or t1.s
   union all
   select c.id, t.datetime, t.value, floor((r_num + 1)/3)::int, r_num + 1 
   from cte c join tbl t on date(t.datetime) = date(c.dt) + interval '1 day'
)
select date(t1.min_dt)|| ' - ' || date(t1.max_dt), t1.sum_val from (
   select c.id, c.cnt, min(c.dt) min_dt, max(c.dt) max_dt, sum(c.val) sum_val from cte c
group by c.id, c.cnt) t1
order by t1.id, t1.cnt
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N9QESdFV) for results on both the sample and a larger set of test rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as
(select min(dt)::date min, max(dt)::date max from table1)

,ranges as(
select (min + (i) *3* interval '1 day')::date inidate
,case when (min::date + ((2+i*3) * interval '1 day' )) <= max::date  then 
  (min::date + ((2+i*3) * interval '1 day' ))::date
 else
   max::date
 end as endDate
FROM  cte cross join (SELECT generate_series(0,1000,1) AS i) numbers
where 
(min::date + ((2+(i-1)*3) * interval '1 day' )) <= max)

select inidate::text||' - '||enddate::text period, sum(t.value) valued 

from ranges r
inner join table1 t on t.dt::date between r.iniDate and r.enddate
group by inidate::text||' - '||enddate::text
order by inidate::text||' - '||enddate::text
```

### Test

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1cee2/58